# Why am I getting error: no matching function for call to 'send_sequence_to_device(std::map<const std::basic_string<char>, lm_device_t*>&)'|

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the a function in manager.cpp:

```
///Calculate of the time slot
bool link_layer_manager_t::calc_ts_clk_est_duration_seconds()
{

    std::map<const string_t, lm_device_t *> setRegMsg={};
    vector<response_t> res;

    setRegMsg={{"trx_set_jr_fraction' + frac_msb +' ' + frac_lsb +'", &rx}};
    response_t r = send_sequence_to_device(setRegMsg,res);
}
```

The `send_sequence_to_device` is a floationg function which in a different file (the manager.cpp include this file).
Here is the function:

```
template<class T>
response_t send_sequence_to_device( std::map<const string_t,T*> msg2device_p, std::vector<response_t>& result_list, ushort num_attempts=SEND_NUM_ATTEMPTS )
{
    bool is_ok_flag = true;
    response_t r;
    raftor1_logs_t* rlogs;
    typename std::map<const string_t, T*>::iterator msg_it;
    for( msg_it=msg2device_p.begin(); msg_it!=msg2device_p.end() and is_ok_flag; msg_it++ )
    {
        r = msg_it->second->send(msg_it->first, true, num_attempts);
        result_list.push_back(r);
        is_ok_flag = is_ok_flag and is_ok(r);

        if( not(is_ok_flag) )
        {
            stringstream ss;
            ss << "ALERT: Sequence aborted due to error on message [" << msg_it->first << "] ";
            if( r.erred() )
                ss << "due to communication failure.";
            else
                ss << "with error message [" << r.msg << "].";
            rlogs->alert.begin_record();
            rlogs->alert.write( ss.str() );
            rlogs->alert.end_record();
        }
    }

    if( is_ok_flag )
        r.set_ok("ok.\n");

    return r;
}
```

When I try to build the function I get the following error:

error: no matching function for call to 'send_sequence_to_device(std::map, lm_device_t*>&)'|

Why?

Comment: Probably because no matching function can be instantiated.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams- but the manager.cpp "know" the file with the function send...

Comment: Do you have your template function split between a header file and a cpp file?

Comment: @NathanOliver- yes It have.

Comment: Have you tried changing your call to `send_sequence_to_device<lm_device_t>(setRegMsg,res)` to see if you get a more illuminating compiler error?